# DNS - DKIM wright p param

Tags: dns, dkim

I have DKIM public key file with content:

> 201801._domainkey       IN      TXT     ( "v=DKIM1; h=rsa-sha256; k=rsa; s=email; "
>             "p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0vM6wkKc/bbTl9vLhkKHIQbkLna7RI0D8iJw8ZGzzNKU4+mnfkuujbzJmF1NHspXMiHd7UsXUDOHbNA7oBt9MEo+JbPGJ38ldJfmdjAiD0ONjkgtMwDyeXQE4Yf$
>             "JfGCWlejWabYBpXpZ5sMeWwjthOcXk8x1xa279TDUNCL6R2wD0rABSE3zM/nQVwFahm5bcwMdsBKR2tQtn7ciPwFFtHSdvFd3EETSSbSrNIDZrgI243zXTZ9h29yO3WlyHRvjsHQIDAQAB" )  ; ----- DKIM key 20180$

What value i should set into DNS? Is it ok that p parametr contains `"`?

Answer (score 0):

For your public key there's no need to have any quotes at all in there so I'd remove them. I'm not sure if you added this just for this post or if it's part of the key but you wouldn't want the beginning and ending ( ) either but you may have just added those for posting here. Also, I don't think you want what appears to be a line break or space where the quotes are you're referencing.

An essential step (for any email authentication) is to validate your DKIM keys using at least one tool:

• [DKIM Core](http://dkimcore.org/tools/keycheck.html)
• [DKIM Inspector](https://www.dmarcian.com/dkim-inspector/)